# While loop in GNU linux shell script has a hard time incrementing date to next month

Tags: linux, shell, date, while-loop, gnu

This loop should print the dates of each day from 9/28 through 10/14, but it seems to get confused after the end of September.  However, it eventually moves onto October.  Is there something wrong with the syntax or date formatting or incrementation?

Here is the code in `test2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is meant to run on the data-science server, so uses GNU syntax
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
cd $BASEDIR

start_date=$(date -d 2015-09-28 +"%y%m%d")
end_date=$(date -d 2015-10-14 +"%y%m%d")

dateTs=$start_date

while [ $dateTs -le $end_date ]
do
  date=$(date -d $dateTs +%Y-%m-%d)
  printf '%s\n' $date
  dateTs=$(($dateTs+1))
done
```

This is the result of running `sh test2.sh`:

```
2015-09-28
2015-09-29
2015-09-30
date: invalid date ‘150931’

date: invalid date ‘150932’

date: invalid date ‘150933’

... [leaving out a bunch more of these] ...

date: invalid date ‘150997’

date: invalid date ‘150998’

date: invalid date ‘150999’

date: invalid date ‘151000’

2015-10-01
2015-10-02
2015-10-03
2015-10-04
2015-10-05
2015-10-06
2015-10-07
2015-10-08
2015-10-09
2015-10-10
2015-10-11
2015-10-12
2015-10-13
2015-10-14
```

... I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When you add 1 to `150930` you get `150931`. Since September doesn't have 31 days, that's not a valid date.

Comment: BTW, you'll get a LOT of error like that if you try to cross years, since there are no months from 13 to 99.

Comment: Thanks- I should clarify that presently I don't know much about shell scripting.  Is there a way to increment a date so that it goes to the next date, even if it's in another month?

Comment: Note that GNU `date` works so that `date -d '2015-09-30 + 1 day'` produces
`Thu Oct  1 00:00:00 PDT 2015`.  With a controlled output format, you can avoid spurious looping.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use ordinary arithmetic on date strings, because most numbers are not valid dates. When you go past the end of a month, the day part will be outside the possible range of dates. And when you go past the end of the year, you'll have invalid months.

The `date` command allows you to specify increments. Use:

```
start_date=2015-09-28
end_date=2015-10-14

date=$start_date

while [[ $date <= $end_date ]]
do
  printf '%s\n' $date
  date=$(date -d "$date + 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
done
```